# How to redirect autocomplete search box to show view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, autocomplete

I'm new to rails and I would appreciate your input. I created an app with an autocomplete search box. When the user types a disease, I want him to be redirected to the "show" view with some info about this disease. The autocomplete works fine, but there's no redirection.

Here's my full code
https://gist.github.com/ollac21/0ab136d46d06e37fb2c2

My routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :diseases do
  get :search, :on => :collection
end


root 'diseases#index'
end
```

My controller

```
class DiseasesController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_disease, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { @diseases = Disease.search(params[:term]) }
  end
end


def show
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_disease
  @disease = Disease.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def disease_params
  params.require(:disease).permit(:name)
end

end
```

My view

```
<h1> Type any disease to find info about it </h1>

<div class="diseases-search">
<input type="text" id="diseases-search-txt" autofocus>
<div class="results" id="diseases-search-results"></div>
</div>


<script>
$(function() {
new app.Diseases;
});
</script>
```

My Javascript

```
    app.Diseases = function() {
  this._input = $('#diseases-search-txt');
  this._initAutocomplete();
};

app.Diseases.prototype = {
  _initAutocomplete: function() {
    this._input
      .autocomplete({
        source: '/diseases',
        appendTo: '#diseases-search-results',
        select: $.proxy(this._select, this)
      })
      .autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = $.proxy(this._render, this);
  },

  _render: function(ul, item) {
    var markup = [

      '<span class="name">' + item.name + '</span>'

    ];
    return $('<li>')
      .append(markup.join(''))
      .appendTo(ul);
  },

  _select: function(e, ui) {
    this._input.val(ui.item.name);
    return false;
  }
};
```

Plus, I've used this to "inspire myself"
https://github.com/lugolabs/tutorials/tree/master/amazing

I would really appreciate some help
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the route for each `desease` in the controller ( or `json view` ) and add it to the `json` response. Then add the link to your markup:

```
_render: function(ul, item) {
  var markup = [
    // Assuming that item is the disease record
    '<a href='+ item.the_url +'><span class="name">' + item.name + '</span></a>'

  ];
return $('<li>')
  .append(markup.join(''))
  .appendTo(ul);
},
```

Comment: Thx. I took your idea. I added a route for each disease in the controller and added it to the json response. Instead of changing the markup, though, I changed the "select" option from the autocomplete widget to redirect the result to the show view. By changing the markup, only the word was redirecting to the view. 
    select: function(e, ui) {
          window.location.href = ui.item.the_url;
        }